# How to compress a DB backup before saving it to the disk?

Tags: c#, compression, database-backups

I'm working on something that will backup and save said backup of a database to a specified location. I'd like to know if there's a way to compress the `.bak` file after it's generate, but before I actually save it to its destination without getting the backup, zipping the `.bak` and then deleting the uncompressed version.

```
SqlConnection objconnection = new SqlConnection(connString);
ServerConnection con = new ServerConnection(objconnection.DataSource.ToString());
Server server = new Server(con);
Backup source = new Backup();
source.Action = BackupActionType.Database;
source.Database = dbName;

BackupDeviceItem destination = new BackupDeviceItem(dbName+".bak" , DeviceType.File); 

//-->Zip the backup prior to actually saving backup

source.Devices.Add(destination);

source.SqlBackup(server);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this isn't possible and I have to create the .BAK backup file and then compress/zip it before sending it off.

Answer (score 0):

If you create a stored procedure and then call it from within your code that should work, take a look at [method 2](https://www.eukhost.com/kb/how-to-reduceshrink-the-sql-server-database-size/) which illustrate how it can be done via using transact SQL command

Answer (score 0):

SqlServer backups have product support for compression.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/backup-compression-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017

If you follow this method you will get the benefit of being able to restore directly from the media on disk rather than having to expand the media first.